# Changing colour of path drawn in UIView draw(_rect)

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I have drawn a circle using `addArc` in my `UIView` subclass' `draw(_ rect: CGrect)` function. It draws fine initially, but when some UI trigger occurs, I wanted to change the fill colour of the circle by changing the value of a `isFilledIn` property.

However, my circles do not change when the `isFilledIn` property is modified. The `isFilledIn` property and the `draw` method are both being called as expected, but the appearance of the circle does not change. It seems once the circles are drawn, their appearance is stuck.

```
var isFilledIn = false {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {            
        context.setLineWidth(outlineWidth)
        myOutlineColor.setStroke()

        if isFilledIn {
            myFilledColor.setFill()
        } else {
            myEmptyColor.setFill()
        }

        let center = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        let radius = (frame.size.width - 10) / 2

        context.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)

        context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    }
}
```

I tried adding a `context.clear(rect)` but that had no effect. I also considered saving the `CGPath` to a property and just trying to modify that instead of calling `setNeedsDisplay` but I wasn't sure how to apply the fill colour changes if all I have is a `CGPath`.

I realize there are other, potentially easier / more efficient ways to create circles (e.g. `UIBezierPath`, or a `UIView` with a corner radius), but I'm specifically trying to understand Core Graphics better and I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to me that this just cannot happen. Maybe you have another view on top of your view? Are you sure the two colors are actually different? It seems to me the error will be somewhere else.

Comment: The colors are definitely different, but I did a quick check and I am actually seeing more views in my superview than I expect… Looking into that, presumably that's the problem, a pre-emptive thank you just in case.

Comment: Ah, I was calling the view setup code in `layoutSubviews` and that is being called twice. Pretty basic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was calling my view setup code in `layoutSubviews`, forgetting that that method may be called multiple times (and it was). So as [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) pointed out in the comments above, I did have overlapping views. There was a second circle on top of the one I was trying to redraw.

Adding an `if` statement inside `layoutSubviews` to prevent it from setting up the circle multiple times fixed it for me.

Thank you Sulthan.